# How can i avoid to split text into another column using css column property?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page which is having different layouts using css coulmn property, but unfortunately the when i insert a image on 1st column the text is spliting into second column

```css
 * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            width: 21cm;
            min-height: 29.7cm;
            padding: 1cm;
            margin: 1cm auto;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background: white;
        }

        .main-container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .main-container>#mainStory {
            -webkit-column-width: 100px;
            -moz-column-width: 100px;
            column-width: 200px;
            column-rule: 1px solid black;
            padding: 2px;
            text-align: justify;
            text-justify: inter-word;
        }

        .inner-container {
            column-count: 2;
            column-rule: 1px solid black;
            break-inside: avoid;
        }

        .inner-container>#leftStory {
            -webkit-column-width: 100px;
            -moz-column-width: 100px;
            column-width: 150px;
            column-rule: 1px solid black;
            padding: 2px;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            text-align: justify;
            text-justify: inter-word;
        }

        .inner-container>#rightStory {
            -webkit-column-width: 100px;
            -moz-column-width: 100px;
            column-width: 150px;
            column-rule: 1px solid black;
            padding: 2px;
            float: right;
            text-align: justify;
            text-justify: inter-word;
        }

        h1,
        h3 {
            column-span: all;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h3>img{
            width:100%;
        }

        h1>img {
            width: 100%;
        }

        @page {
            size: A4;
            margin: 0;
        }

        @media print {
            html,
            body {
                width: 210mm;
                height: 280mm;
            }
        }
```

```html
    <div class="main-container">
        <div id="mainStory">
            <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?
                <br/>
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beach-exotic-holiday-248797.jpg&fm=jpg"/>
            </h1>
            <b>Lorem Ipsum </b>
            is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
            since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
            unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
            and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem
            Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it
            over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one
            of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the
            word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and
            1.10.33 of \"de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum\" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This
            book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum,
            \"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..\", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
        </div>
        <br/>

    </div>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div id="leftStory">
            <h3>Why do we use it?<br/><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=abandoned-forest-industry-34950.jpg&fm=jpg"/></h3>
            <b>Contrary to popular belief </b>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
            been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
            typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
            containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
            versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div id="rightStory">
            <h3>Where can I get some?</h3>
            <b>Contrary to popular belief </b>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority
            have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly
            believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing
            hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks
            as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet.
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please check the fiddle when i inserting image on left below column the text is going into its second column.
i want that when the image is large the text will split according to that image into that column rather then spliting in second column.

Comment: Would you mind pointing out the issue? https://jsfiddle.net/yqr8Lzeb/2/ Seems fine

Comment: Thanks for comment :) . my issue is I don't want to split the text which is on `#leftStory` with an image to go to the `#rightStory`, like if you remove the second image on fiddle the text will be on two columns, but when i insert an image into it the text is going into `"#rightStory"` div.

Comment: I haven't used those `column` arguments before so I'm afraid I might not be able to help you with my limited time. I'm guessing it is those that are breaking it a little though. (But don't take my word for it)

Answer (score 0):

The overall desing is weird and I don't understand the logic behind it, is like avery old school box model made with divs, plus it has a very weird concept behind escenes such as centimeters to measure width and heigth instead of viewport or rem.

Now, what you need can not be done the way you want but it can be done

```css
* {
           box-sizing: border-box;
           -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       }

       body {
           width: 21cm;
           min-height: 29.7cm;
           padding: 1cm;
           margin: 1cm auto;
           border-radius: 5px;
           background: white;
       }

       .main-container {
           display: flex;
           justify-content: center;
       }

       .main-container>#mainStory {
           -webkit-column-width: 100px;
           -moz-column-width: 100px;
           column-width: 200px;
           column-rule: 1px solid black;
           padding: 2px;
           text-align: justify;
           text-justify: inter-word;
       }

       .inner-container {
           display: grid;
           grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;           
           break-inside: avoid;
       }

       #leftStory {
           -webkit-column-width: 100px;
           -moz-column-width: 100px;
           column-width: 150px;
           column-rule: 1px solid black;
           padding: 2px;
           float: left;
           text-align: center;
           text-align: justify;
           text-justify: inter-word;
           border-right: 1px solid black;
           padding-right: 7px;
           margin-right: 5px;
       }

       #rightStory {
           -webkit-column-width: 100px;
           -moz-column-width: 100px;
           column-width: 150px;
           column-rule: 1px solid black;
           padding: 2px;
           float: right;
           text-align: justify;
           text-justify: inter-word;
       }

       h1,
       h3 {
           column-span: all;
           text-align: center;
       }
       h3>img{
           width:100%;
       }

       h1>img {
           width: 100%;
       }

       @page {
           size: A4;
           margin: 0;
       }

       @media print {
           html,
           body {
               width: 210mm;
               height: 280mm;
           }
       }
```

```html
        <div class="main-container">
            <div id="mainStory">
                <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?
                    <br/>
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beach-exotic-holiday-248797.jpg&fm=jpg"/>
                </h1>
                <b>Lorem Ipsum </b>
                is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
                since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem
                Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it
                over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one
                of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the
                word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and
                1.10.33 of \"de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum\" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This
                book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum,
                \"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..\", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
            </div>
            <br/>

        </div>
        <div class="inner-container">
            <div id="leftStory">
                <h3>Why do we use it?<br/><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=abandoned-forest-industry-34950.jpg&fm=jpg"/></h3>
                <b>Contrary to popular belief </b>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
                been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
                typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
                containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
                versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
            <div id="rightStory">
                <h3>Where can I get some?</h3>
                <b>Contrary to popular belief </b>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority
                have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly
                believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing
                hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks
                as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet.lteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly
                believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing
                hidden in the middle of text. All the Llteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly
                believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing
                hidden in the middle of text. All the Llte le of text. All the Llte le of text. All the Llte le of text. All the Llte
            </div>
        </div>
```

> please consider to remake this project avoiding using those weird
>   things you are doing like nesting images inside H1 tags, centimeters
>   as width and height, that weird span colum, etc... It looks terribly
>   wrong wrong on firefox and on mobile devices.
>   [here you can see how it works on CodePen](https://codepen.io/jeanbelmont/pen/JBrrGe)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You may add following CSS

> img { float:left;  }

Comment: It does nothing

Comment: Change this line
 <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=abandoned-forest-industry-34950.jpg&fm=jpg" />
            </h1>
            <br/>
                

To this line:
==========
 <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?
                
            </h1>
            <br/>
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=abandoned-forest-industry-34950.jpg&fm=jpg" width="50" />